# Open TabsPage from a landing page?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to display first a landing, then a tabs page, but I'm not sure how to specify the `TabsPage` in **landing.ts**.

**landing.ts:**

```
  startApp() {
    //window.localStorage.setItem('username', 'admin');

    this.navCtrl.setRoot('TabsPage', {}, {
      animate: true,
      direction: 'forward'
    });
  }
```

**Error:**

> Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: TabsPage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to deeplink to your TabsPage (`.setRoot('TabsPage')`)

```
 startApp() {
    //window.localStorage.setItem('username', 'admin');

    this.navCtrl.setRoot('TabsPage', {}, {
      animate: true,
      direction: 'forward'
    });
  }
```

Instead, try

```
import { TabsPage } from 'wherever/it/is'

startApp() {
  // no quotes around TabsPage
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
}
```

Comment: Wow... I removed the quotes and it worked... since I've already imported the page before... Thanks a lot! :-))